# Check if li is checked in mdl list

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, html-lists, material-design-lite

I work with MDL (material Design Lite) and I created a checklist with this html code.

```
<li class="mdl-list__item">
    <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
      <i class="material-icons  mdl-list__item-avatar">person</i>
      Bryan Cranston
    </span>
    <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action">
      <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="list-checkbox-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="list-checkbox-1" class="mdl-checkbox__input" checked />
      </label>
    </span>
  </li>
```

This result in this

[image]

Now I want to save the Bryan Cranston to my firebase database if it is checked by pressing a button but I don't know how to control if it is checked or not. 
I can do it manually

```
addFriendButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
           var username = (should be "Bryan Cranston")
           var ref = firebase.database().ref("friends").child(user.uid).child(username).set(true);
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing that you can do is retrieve the `checked` attribute from the checkbox element. This element is a Boolean, true if it is checked and false if not. So whenever the button is clicked, you can retrieve the element and check if it is checked like so:

```
addFriendButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    ...
    if(document.getElementById('list-checkbox-1').checked) {
        // add him to the database
    }
});
```